# Django: product variants for ecommerce

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

I'm trying to build an ecommerce and to configure product variants and attributes. In my product variant models, I'd like to access all of the selected attributes from the related product and add a value for each product.

For example, if I create a  new product and chosose two attributes for the variants: color and size, I'd like to be able to create dynamically a field for each of them when creating a variant for this product.

**Here's what I have in my models.py file:**

```
class Product(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products')
    allow_variants = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    product_attributes = models.ManyToManyField("attribute")

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

    class Meta :
        ordering = ("name",)

class Attribute(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

    def get_all_attr_variants(self) :
        variants = AttributeVariant.objects.filter(attribute__name=self.name)
        return variants

class AttributeVariant(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

    class Meta :
        ordering = ('name',)

class ProductVariant(models.Model) :
```

Please help me if you have any idea of how I could do it.
Thanks!

Comment: may be simple solution is json field?

Comment: Do you have any idea of how I could use JSON in this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

Django does not allow dynamically adding or removing fields. The best way to get this effect is using a "AttibuteValue" class,
like this:

```
class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ProductAttributeValue(models.Model):
    variant = models.ForeignKey(ProductVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(AttributeVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    value = models.CharField()  # Depending on what type you want
```

You can easily get all attributes of a variant by selecting `ProductAttributeValues` with the correct variant and attribute.

Comment: "Django does not allow dynamically adding or removing attributes" => of course it does. What you can't do is dynamically adding fields to a model, for very obvious reasons.

Comment: That's not really what I imagined... What I'd like to do is go on the product detail page and click on 'add product variant' and get fields based on the selected attributes of the product. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You are right, I'm talking about fields, not attributes.

Comment: @FantasmoClone27 you could easily quiry all "attribute" classes for a product, and generate html inputs for them in your template. Here I'm just explaining how to store the result in the database